# Calling three tables to insert data. (sqlite3/python)

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

I have normalised three tables (Product, ProductType and ProductGender) and I'm looking to call them in my main program so that the user can successfully enter values and the data be stored in the correct table.

**Here are the SQL tables being created**

```
def create_product_table(): 
    sql = """create table Product
             (ProductID integer,
              Name text,
              primary key(ProductID))""" 
    create_table(db_name, "Product", sql)

def create_product_type_table():
    sql = """create table ProductType
             (ProductID integer,
             Colour text,
             Size text,
             Gender text,
             AmountInStock integer,
             Source text,
             primary key(ProductID, Colour, Size, Gender)
             foreign key(Gender) references ProductGender(Gender)
             foreign key(ProductID) references Product(ProductID))"""
    create_table(db_name, "ProductType", sql) 

def create_product_gender_table():
    sql = """create table ProductGender
             (Gender text,
             Price text,
             primary key(Gender))"""
    create_table(db_name, "ProductGender", sql)
```

**Here are the SQL subroutines**

```
def insert_data(values): 
    with sqlite3.connect("jam_stock.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "insert into Product (Name, ProductID) values (?,?)"
        cursor.execute(sql,values)
        db.commit()

def insert_product_type_data(records): 
    sql = "insert into ProductType(Amount, Size, Colour, Source) values (?,?,?,?)"
    for record in records:
    query(sql,record)

def insert_product_gender_data(records): 
    sql = "insert into ProductGender(Gender, Price) values (?,?)"
    for record in records:
    query(sql, records)

def query(sql,data): #important 
    with sqlite3.connect("jam_stock.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON") #referential integrity 
        cursor.execute(sql,data)
        db.commit()
```

**Below is the code where the user will enter the values.**

```
if ans=="1": #1=to option 'Add Stock'
  a = input("Enter Gender: ")
  b = float(input("Enter Price: "))
  c = int(input("Enter ProductID: "))
  d = input("Enter Name: ")
  e = input("Enter Size: ")
  f = input("Enter Colour: ")
  g = input("Enter Source: ")
  h = input("Enter Amount: ")
  #code calling tables should be here
```

Help is gratefully appreciated. Seriously not sure how to link the 3 tables with the user's input.

This is what I did before I normalised the database. So the one table in 'Product' would be updated instead of adding an already existing product. Obviously that has changed now, since I've created two new tables but I can't successfully add a product let alone edit one.

```
def update_product(data): #subroutine for editing stock
    with sqlite3.connect("jam_stock.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "update Product set Name=?, Price=?, Amount=?, Size=?, Colour=?, Source=?, Gender=? where ProductID=?"
        cursor.execute(sql,data)
        db.commit()
```

Comment: Among the serious problems with this code, `insert into Product (Gender, Name, ProductID)` in `insert_data` can't possibly work because you're created the `Product` table with only two fields (Name and ProductID), **not** the "Gender" field in which you're trying to insert a value.  The other two `insert_...` functions use a mysterious `query` which you never mention anywhere else.  And "calling a table" is a meaningless utterance in any SQL.  Lastly, what if the user enters a key that's already in a table -- how do you want to **update** it then? Pls edit the Q to clarify some of this!-)

Comment: I've added the query and amended the insert_data. I'm not sure of the specific term, but I want the users input for Gender to refer to the table ProductGender and the users input for Name to refer to Product etc. I'm unsure of what command/statement to use for this..

Comment: I see your edit has fixed the problems, great (except what happens in case the user enters data for **already existing** records, I'll point it out again below).

Comment: I have a subroutine to update the product instead of add it again, I'll add it to the post.

Comment: the SQL in the `update_product` routine is broken as it tries to update **seven** fields in the `Product` table which has just **one** besides the PK.  Just breaking it into 3 updates on the 3 tables won't work either, as there may be conflicts with **other** PKs (e.g the `Gender` PK in the `ProductGender` table) -- so **much** more precision on your part, about the **exact, detailed** outcome you're trying to pursue, is indispensable if any working code is to be proposed!-)

Answer (score 1):

Given the code you show above, and **assuming** (BIG assumption, see later!) that the user never enters data for existing records, the following code should do it:

```
query('insert into Product (Name, ProductID) values (?,?)',
      [d, c])
query('insert into ProductGender (Gender, Price) values (?,?)',
      [a, b])
query('insert into ProductType (ProductID, Colour, Size, Gender, '
         AmountInStock, Source) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)',
      [c, f, e, a, h, g])
```

Your use of arbitrary single-letter variable names makes this very hard to follow, of course, but I think I got the correspondence right:-).

Much more important is the problem that you never tell us **what** to do if the user enters data for an **already** existing record in one or more of the three tables (as determined by the respective primary keys).

For example, what if `Product` already has a record with a `ProductID` of `foobar` and a `Name` of `Charlemagne`; and the user enters `ProductID` as `foobar` and a `Name` of `Alexandre`; what do you **want** to happen in this case?  You **never** tell us!

The code I present above will just fail the whole sequence because of the attempt to insert a new record in `Product` with an already-existing primary key; if you don't catch the exception and print an error message this will in fact crash your whole program.

But maybe you want to do something completely different in such cases -- and there are **so** many possibilities that we can't just blindly guess!

So please edit your Q to clarify in minute detail what's supposed to happen in each case of primary key "duplication" in one or more table (unless you're fine with just crashing in such cases!-), and the SQL and Python code to make exactly-that happen will follow.  But of course **we** can't decide what the semantics of your program are meant to be...!-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The user **does** enter data for existing records, through an update subroutine (template shown in the post, but outdated). As you can probably tell, I'm new to SQL and Python, so I haven't found a way to avoid the issue of replacing data under a ProductID I wished not to replace. How would I go about this?

Comment: @ted, if you just want to silently ignore duplicates (w/o altering the relevant table[s]), use `insert or ignore` instead of just `insert`); if you want to give warning msgs in such case, use `insert` within a `try/except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e` statement and give the error msg in the `except` branch; etc -- far too many possibilities to list in a comment, or even in an answer -- decide **exactly** what needs to happen, etc).

Comment: ah, thank you. One last thing - if I want to view  **all** the products added, how do I view all three tables using `select *` without viewing ProductID, Name etc. more than once?

Comment: @Ted, for that purpose, you `JOIN` those tables; but, that's really a totally different Q and the StackOverflow norm is "one question per question" -- so I earnestly encourage you to post that separate question as a separate question, then **accept** this answer as it seems to have been helpful to you.